# Use ImageMagick to resize and then crop an image from command line

Tags: imagemagick

I have a jpg image which I want to resize as follows:

1. Keeping the aspect-ratio of the image same, resize it to as close as 640x360 as possible, without keeping any portion of the new image "blank"/"empty". That is, it's okay if after resizing, it becomes 800x360 or 640x420, but not okay if it is 400x360 (because 400 is lesser than 640) or 640x200 (because 200 is lesser than 360).
2. After this, I need to center-crop the above-resized image to the ratio of 16:9.

What would be the easiest set of shell commands which can be used to achieve this using imagemagick?

I tried both

1. `convert 'orig_image.jpg' -resize 640x360 -gravity Center -crop 640x360+0+0 'changed_image.jpg'` and
2. `convert 'orig_image.jpg' -resize 640x360 -gravity Center -crop 640x360+0+0 +repage 'changed_image.jpg'`

but none worked. `-resize 640x360` is resizing the image, but not fulfilling my above requirement. That is, `2448x3264` is resizing to `270x360` instead of `640x480`

Comment: This is just lazy. You can easily look it up yourself: ImageMagick has an awesome documentation. See "Resizing and scaling examples" http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/ and "Cutting and bordering examples" http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/

Comment: I already read that.
What I understood after reading that is, I need to do `convert 'orig_image.jpg' -resize 640x360 -gravity Center -crop 640x360+0+0 'changed_image.jpg'`. But it is not working. It is only doing the resize, but not the crop that is supposed to be done to the resized image after that. Please reply if you can help regarding this.

Comment: Hmm. Does `+repage` help? `convert 'orig_image.jpg' -resize 640x360 -gravity Center -crop 640x360+0+0 +repage 'changed_image.jpg'`. If it doesn't, why not edit the question to show what you are doing right now (the `convert` call), and what is happening right now (including an image that illustrates the problem)

Comment: Still didn't work. I edited the question.

Comment: Can you add the original image and the result you are getting at the moment? (And ideally one of the desired result)

Comment: I am doing `convert 'orig.jpg' -resize 640x360 -gravity Center -crop 640x360+0+0 +repage 'changed.jpg'`

Results:

original: `orig.jpg JPEG 2448x3264 2448x3264+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.406MB 0.000u 0:00.000`
changed: `changed.jpg JPEG 270x360 270x360+0+0 8-bit sRGB 14.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000`

Comment: No, I mean can you upload the actual images so we can see them?

Comment: Ah, I think that `-resize 640x360` itself is not successfully doing my requirement (`That is, it's okay if after resizing, it becomes 800x360 or 640x420, but not okay if it is 400x360 (because 400 is lesser than 640) or 640x200 (because 200 is lesser than 360)`) either.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use this:

```
convert orig.jpg \
        -resize 640x360^ \
        -gravity Center \
        -extent 640x360
        changed.jpg
```

Where `-resize 64x360^` preserves the minimum aspect ratio, and `-extent 640x360` (without `+0+0`) respected `-gravity Center`